# Using HOSTALIASES for PHP-FPM

Tags: php, linux

There's a way to per-process override name resolution
[process-local override of name resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934027/process-local-override-of-name-resolution)
using HOSTALIASES.
Do you think it's applicable to PHP-FPM workers too?
I have this line in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:

```
env[HOSTALIASES] = /etc/hosts.php-fpm
```

And when I examine $_SERVER, I see HOSTALIASES, but the actual override in the hosts.php-fpm (127.0.0.1 example.com) is not effective, it's returned from the nameservers.
Do you have a suggestion on how to make (a similar solution) work?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use HOSTALIASES in the wrong way. To be respected, alias should meet 2 requirements:

1. should not contain dots (here is [code](https://github.com/andikleen/glibc/blob/b0399147730d478ae45160051a8a0f00f91ef965/resolv/nss_dns/dns-host.c#L181) which, I believe, checks it). That is mentioned in man of [hostname(7)](https://www.linux.com/learn/docs/man/3279-hostname7)
2. target should be complete hostname. That is also mentioned in hostname doc.

So, your record in HOSTALIASES should look like

```
example someexample.com
```

In case you need to alias the ip, you can use something like [xip.io](http://xip.io/)

Generally, that should work with any php function which relies on gethostbyname (that also true for php-fpm).